# Script Google Sheets that will count the amount of cells with a specific background colour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologies if this is the wrong place but I feel like tearing my hair out. I've scoured google for a script that will count the cells with a background colour, as this seems to not be built into google sheets. I always seem to get some variation of this:

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

I run this and it works fine, once. The second time onwards it breaks. And every single website or blog appear to have this exact script, or slighty modified version, and every version produces this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of null
> countColoredCells   @ Code.gs:6

I scour the comments section with people complaining about this error and sometimes people respond with solutions, but nothing I've tried seems to fix this error. I've searched dozens of google results for either a script, or a fix to this error with no success.

Comment: What is your locale? Can you provide the result of `var formula = activeRange.getFormula()`? Is `countRange` in the same sheet?

Comment: I believe the problem is this function will only work when the cursor is in the cell containing the formula.  If you move the cursor the activeRange changes, the formula is blank so formula.match returns null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345277/7215091

Comment: @Cooper, that routine counts all cells.  What this function does is pass 2 parameters countRange and colorRef as ranges.  But of course the ranges are received by the function as values.  The regex parses the formula and gets the A1 notation instead to use in a getRange() method.  Clever idea, but flawed in this case.

Comment: @Cooper its tomato

Answer (score 0):

Description

The OP script will not work when the user moves the cursor to another cell. `var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();` this will change the range when the cell is recalculated.  If there is no formula in that cell formula.match will return null.

Instead enclose the range parameters to `=countColoredCells("A1:A10",B1)` in quotes.

Script

```
// range parameteres need to be enclosed in quotation marks
// formula in the form =countColoredCells("A1:A10","B1");
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var bg = spread.getRange(countRange).getBackgrounds()
  var color = spread.getRange(colorRef).getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Reference

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp