# Using Apps Script to count background colours in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologies in advance for the long one! Let me know if you need any more info/example of the full js file/spreadsheet I'm using.

## Context:

I'm having some trouble getting GAS to work, counting the number of background colours in a child's schedule I've created.

I have a simple week view, broken into 30 min chunks from 5:30am to 7:30pm. I've then coloured different cells based on being at home or not, and different recurring events.
That leaves me with something like the following:
[image]

What I am trying to do is count the number of cells that are purple, orange and green. I'll divide these by 2 to then get the number of hours at each location throughout the week.

## Steps Taken:

A key piece here is that I **need to be using merged cells** within the target range that I'm counting.

The following has been a big help: [Script Google Sheets that will count the amount of cells with a specific background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412087/script-google-sheets-that-will-count-the-amount-of-cells-with-a-specific-backgro)

This got me to use a custom function as follows:

```js
//Gets the count of cells with a particular colour within the range. Merged cells count as 1
function countColouredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};

//Usage in cell formula: "=countcolouredcells($E$11:$K$39,L46)" where $E$11:$K$39 is the range to count the occurances of cells with the same background as L46
```

However this counts merged cells as 1, not the number of cells the merge is for. E.g. in the picture above, Monday's green "School" merged cell is 1, where as I want the function to count it as 14.

Embarking on a bit more of an investigation, I've created (copied and adapted from other people on stackoverflow) two functions that break apart merged cells, then stitch them back together.

```js
var mergedRanges;

function breakApartRange(breakRange){
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var fullRange = activeSheet.getRange(breakRange);
  
  //break merged cells
  mergedRanges = fullRange.getMergedRanges();
  mergedRanges.forEach(range => range.setValue(range.breakApart().getValue()));
};


function reMergeRange(breakRange){
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var fullRange = activeSheet.getRange(breakRange);
  
  //re merge cells
  mergedRanges.forEach(range => range.merge());
};
```

A small complication with this is that you cannot call the breakApart() method within a custom function from a formula. A workaround I found for this was to run my custom function from a custom menu item that I create in the onOpen method.

```js
//Adds a menu item to run the function:
// The onOpen function is executed automatically every time a Spreadsheet is loaded
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];

  menuEntries.push({name: "Calculate Hourly Split", functionName: "calcHourlySplitByColour"});

  ss.addMenu("CustomFunctions", menuEntries);
};
```

This means that I needed to use static references for the range I wanted to count, and the references to the colours, but that's acceptable for what I'm doing. Now I have a custom function called `calcHourlySplitByColour` that is triggered by opening the menu item, that will:

1. break apart the merges
2. call another custom function (`countColouredCells`) to count the coloured cells
3. store that count in a seperate cell so i can view it
4. remerge the cells back so that it looks like the original view.

Individually, this works (the break apart and remerge I have tested and work when called from the custom menu item, and the `countColouredCells` seems to work if I just call it from typing into a formula in the sheet.)

## Issue I'm Stuck On:

My issue comes when I try to stitch it all together, in particular, when I try to use the countColouredCells, called via the custom menu item. To make it work I need to pass the ranges into countColouredCells statically, but I always end up getting an issue when it runs the pop() method:

```js
//Gets the count of cells with a particular colour within the range. Merged cells count as 1
function countColouredCells2(countRange,colorRef) {
 
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(countRange);
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  //Testing code just to see if the activeRange was null - it wasn't, this returned "1st PopCalibri" in the alert
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("1st Pop" + activeRange.getFontFamily());
  
  //This is the line that causes the error (i.e. I never see an alert for "2nd Pop"):
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("2nd Pop");
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Post 2nd Pop");
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

The above is a work in progress, refactoring my original `countColouredCells` method. I know that I haven't done anything to address the colorRef parameter yet, but the line of code that is causing the issue:

```js
    var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
```

is just addressing the first parameter, countRange. Here is the error I get:
[image]

[image]

An example of the spreadsheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iufv_PnUc4GNKg5V9CHwRewtV8rHRM83bD_AnNujGFw/edit?usp=sharing). I haven't actually tried to see the apps script for a shared sheet before so incase you can't see it, [here's](https://pastebin.com/SJkK2Bvg) the version that goes with this example spreadsheet.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In this case, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your expected value using the sample Spreadsheet? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, no problem! Even for someone great at english I think the above is hard to understand! I've edited the post - if you look at the bottom you will see two links to the sheet and the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet including your expected values, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the number of background colors of all cells from a sheet including the merged cells using Google Apps Script.
- When your showing Spreadsheet image is used, you want to retrieve `76, 47, 13, 67` for `'#d9d2e9', '#fce5cd', '#cfe2f3', '#d9ead3'`, respectively.

In this case, how about the following answer? The point of this sample script is as follows.

- First, the background colors are retrieved from all cells including the merged cells. In this case, all background colors of merged cells are "#ffffff" except for the 1st cell.
- As the next step, the retrieved background colors of all cells are updated by detecting the merged cells using `getMergedRanges()`.

By this flow, the background colors of all cells can be obtained. When this flow is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:H30");
  const offsetR = range.getRow() - 1;
  const offsetC = range.getColumn() - 1;
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  range.getMergedRanges().forEach(r => {
    const startRow = r.getRow() - 1 - offsetR;
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startCol = r.getColumn() - 1 - offsetC;
    const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    const base = backgrounds[startRow][startCol];
    for (let r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
      for (let c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
        backgrounds[r][c] = base;
      }      
    }
  });
  const checkColorObj = new Map(sheet.getRange("J2:J5").getBackgrounds().map(([j]) => [j, 0]));
  backgrounds.forEach(r => r.forEach(c => {
    if (checkColorObj.has(c)) {
      checkColorObj.set(c, checkColorObj.get(c) + 1);
    }
  }));
  const values = [...checkColorObj.values()].map(e => [e]);

  console.log(values); // You can see the result value in the log.
  sheet.getRange("L2:L5").setValues(values); // This is a sample script for putting the result value to "L2:L5".
}
```

As another sample script, when you want to use this script as a custom function, it becomes as follows. When you test this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("B2:H30")` into a cell. In this case, please set `"B2:H30"` as a string. If you put it as `=SAMPLE(B2:H30)`, an error like `Exception: Range not found` occurs. Please be careful about this.

```js
function SAMPLE(a1Notation) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange(a1Notation);
  const offsetR = range.getRow() - 1;
  const offsetC = range.getColumn() - 1;
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  range.getMergedRanges().forEach(r => {
    const startRow = r.getRow() - 1 - offsetR;
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startCol = r.getColumn() - 1 - offsetC;
    const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    const base = backgrounds[startRow][startCol];
    for (let r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
      for (let c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
        backgrounds[r][c] = base;
      }      
    }
  });
  const checkColorObj = new Map(sheet.getRange("J2:J5").getBackgrounds().map(([j]) => [j, 0]));
  backgrounds.forEach(r => r.forEach(c => {
    if (checkColorObj.has(c)) {
      checkColorObj.set(c, checkColorObj.get(c) + 1);
    }
  }));
  return [...checkColorObj.values()].map(e => [e]);
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above custom function is put into "L2" of your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained. You can see the result values are the same as your expected values.

[image]

**In this case, the reference color is retrieved from "J2:J5" cells. Please be careful about this.**

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getMergedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getmergedranges)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, that works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I cannot upvote (because of rep)

Comment: @Dave Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.